# Projecting a vector onto a line: Question in article

Tags: linear-algebra

At the top of page 3 in the article found [here](http://www.stanford.edu/~sdkamvar/tutorials/mda.pdf), the author claims that the projection of a vector $\mathbf{x_i}$ onto the line $\mathbf{w}$, denoted by $y_i$, is given by
$$
y_i = \mathbf{w}^{T} \mathbf{x_i}
$$

I'm not sure how to interpret this.  Usually isn't a projection of a vector onto a line the component of that vector that goes in the same direction as the line?  Yet, in this case it appears that $y_i$ is a scalar, $\mathbf{w} \cdot \mathbf{x_i}$.

To the best of my knowledge, usually the projection of $\vec{x}$ on a line $l = c \vec{v} | c \in \mathbb{R}$ is given by 
$$
\left ( \frac{\vec{x} \cdot \vec{v}}{\vec{v} \cdot \vec{v}} \right ) \vec{v}
$$

and if $\vec{v}$ is taken to be a unit vector, that is $||\vec{v}|| = 1$, then this reduces to
$$
(\vec{x} \cdot \vec{v}) \vec{v}
$$

I'm not sure how to reconcile the two definitions.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They mean the coefficient $c$ in your notation. Note also that $\mathbf w$ is a unit vector spanning a line ... For them, the direction of $\mathbf w$ makes a difference. Having looked for a moment at the paper, I think it seems sloppy from a mathematical perspective.

Comment: That's strange... so $y_i = (\vec{x} \cdot \vec{v})$ in my notation.  Thanks!

Comment: Provided $\vec v$ is a unit vector.